# Cocoa binding NSTableView within NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to display a NSTableView inside a NSTableView. This is for an iTunes-like albums/tracks view.  So there's a list of 10 albums, each album has some tracks. I want to display the albums in the outer table view and the tracks for each album in the inner.

The first NSTableView is bound to an NSArrayController. Each object in the array has its own "tracks" NSArrayController, but I can't figure out how to tell the 'tracks' NSTableView that its content comes from a property of the 'album' NSTableView.

Comment: Deleted my answer after fiddling with your project.   I can't see how to get `objectValue` bindings working with an array controller embedded in a cell-- Nibs/XCode just seem to think the objectValue is the album, not the nested track cell.  Tellingly, I can't nest an AC object in a cell view in IB either.  My only thought is making the entire album cell a custom view Nib, and having an array controller outlet there to hook up.  In the new Nib, XCode will be able to find the array controller object.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, the source content of the nested array controller comes from objectValue of the owner table cell.  So you can't put the array controller content source to be the objectValue of the table cell.  I'm doing similar in that I want to filter the array content based on the object value

What I'm doing, which seems to be working, is to make a seperate nib file for your nested table cell view, with it's own nstablecellview subclass.  Include the array controller in the nib and create an outlet to it in your cell view subclass.

Register it with the table view in the viewDidLoad method of the tables view controller:

```
NSNib *cellView = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyTableCellView" bundle:nil];
[myTableView registerNib:cellView forIdentifier:@"myTableCellView"];
```

Then, in the awakeFromNib method of your cell view subclass, manually make your bindings that require the object value:

```
[self.arrayController bind:@"contentSet"
                  toObject:self
               withKeyPath:@"objectValue.tracks"
                   options:nil];
```

Voila.

Note that when using this technique, the files Owner of the nib file is not your nstablecellview subclass, it is the view controller of the table view.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in not understanding the MVC-pattern (Model-View-Controller). Content for a view never comes from another view, it comes from model objects via a controller. The content of each of your tableviews always comes from an NSObjectController, or a subclass like NSArrayController. Basically, there are two solution:

- bind the 'tracks' tableview to the selection of the 'album' array controller
- create a 'tracks' array controller and bind it to the selection of the 'album' array controller. Bind the 'tracks' tableview to the 'tracks' array controller

A third solution is to use an NSTreeController with an NSOutlineView but outline views and tree controllers are notoriously hard to work with.

Comment: This is not really correct. It is [standard practice](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH13-SW4) with view-based tables which use `NSTableCellView` as the cell view, for subviews to be bound to the `NSTableCellView`'s `objectValue` property. In effect, the `NSTableCellView` is the object controller for the cell.

Comment: I understand MVC perfectly well. You missed the part where I said that the model was essentially an array of arrays. The outer tableview binds to the top level array. The tricky part was binding the inner tableview to the child arrays. I ended up doing pretty much what @stevesliva recommended and that worked. It's spread out across a few more files than I would have liked but it gets the job done.

Comment: @jsd do you have a sample of how you ended up pulling this off?

Comment: @tofutim nothing in shareable shape. you can't really do it without writing code. the outer tableview class can propagate the inner data to the inner tableview class. there's no way to bind directly.

Comment: @KenThomases Please scroll to the note at the top of the page you linked to where it says there's a note that states: "In an NSView-based table, you bind the table view’s content to the array controller’s arrangedObjects. This differs from the technique you use if you’re working with an NSCell-based table." The 'standard' you're referring to is for view-based tables only.