# Binding across Xibs and Nested TableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I would like to use cocoa bindings for one of my project, where I have three xibs, say A, B and C.

C contains the basic building block with few controls. I am loading it in B's view based tableview(can be multiple instances of Cs).

Then the B's views are loaded in A's view-based tableview.
*Bottomline: it is a nested tableView*.

I am able to populate the data programmatically. Since my data/models are changing frequently I like to go with cocoa-bindings.

Now the question is How to bind this kind of nested tableview?

Yours help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Nested table views are a very bad design choice. Reconsider it. Maybe `NSOutlineView` would be a better choice?

Comment: @Eimantas: Due to some customization and other things I chose nested tableview itself. So am I close here?

Comment: Seem [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575099/cocoa-binding-tableview-within-tableview) ...  you could probably make it work if the B XIB's class is a NSTableCellView subclass with the tableView inside the cell. Within the B XIB, you have the bindings for managing the nested table.  The A XIB has a view-based tabled that has its cellview class set to whatever your B class is.  Beyond that it matters a lot what your model is, and the model might have to change to work with that sort of view hierarchy if you try bindings.